# Symfony2 Formbuilder auto escaping?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a hard space (`&nbsp;`) inside some of my choice options. Somehow, somewhere, they are being escaped. I have tried:

```
{% autoescape false %}
    {{ form_widget(foobar) }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

As well as

```
{{ form_widget(foobar)|raw }}
```

And the following under Twig in `config.yml`

```
autoescape: false
```

Yet the choice fields are still rendered as `&nbsp;Choice Text Here` instead of `Choice Text Here`, and in the source they are being encoded as `&amp;nbsp;Choice Text Here`

In the controller I have:

```
$form   ->add('foo', 'choice', array(
            'label' => 'Foo Label',
            'choices'  => $fooChoices,
            'required' => true));
$form = $form->getForm();
$foobar = $form->createView();
```

If I `print_r` `$fooChoices` I get:

```
Array ( [1] =>  60# FooBar [5] =>  60# BatBar [11] =>  60# DooWop )
```

Which shows me the proper `&nbsp;` (note the double space in front of the 60's). Somewhere between the FormBuilder and the rendering, it is getting escaped.

Is there built-in escaping inside the Form Builder?

What I have deduced is that through the point that the form view is rendered via `$form->createView()` the data is still unescaped. But, by the time it reaches Twig via form_widget, it has been escaped. Doing `form_widget(foobar)|raw` shows this.

**Edit: I have added a workaround as an answer, but I'm still interested in accepting an answer that explains how to prevent the initial escaping from occurring altogether.**

Comment: Can I see the code of your form widget? There is no such feature.

Comment: @David I'm not sure I follow. I'm using the most simple way of rendering a form as per the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-the-form

Comment: I mean within the class where you generate your form, sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: @David edited to provide the specific code and the data it is receiving.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into the same problem with radio labels.  This solves it.

```
{% for child in form %}

  {% autoescape false %}
    {{ child.vars.label }}
  {% endautoescape %}

  {{ form_widget(child) }}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've ended up creating a Twig extension that decodes encoded HTML and added it as a service:

**The extension in Vendor/Bundle/Extensions/Twig**

```
namespace Vendor\Bundle\Extensions\Twig;

class HTMLDecodeTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension 
{

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'htmldecode' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'htmldecode', array(
                'is_safe' => array('html'))
            ),
        );
    }

    // your custom function
    public function htmldecode($string)
    {
        return html_entity_decode($string);
    }

    // Name for Service
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'html_decode_twig_extension';
    }
}
```

**Registering the service in Vendor/Bundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
vendor_bundle.htmldecode:
    class:  Vendor\Bundle\Extensions\Twig\HTMLDecodeTwigExtension
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
```

**The usage:**

```
{{ form_widget(foobar)|htmldecode }}
```

I still don't know where the escaping is being performed, as it is only performed on the data itself (and I tried creating a data event to modify the form's data), but this at least gives me the end result I'm looking for.

Comment: I tried this code and registered the twig extension, but it does not solve the problem when applying solely to `form_label`. You have to apply it to the `form_widget`

Answer (score 3):

What you really should be doing is over-riding the form_label template

```
{% block form_label %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if label is not sameas(false) %}
        {% if not compound %}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if required %}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if label is empty %}
            {% set label = name|humanize %}
        {% endif %}
        {% autoescape false %}<label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</label>{% endautoescape %}
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_label %}
```

Note the addition of the autoescape sections.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best solution, but what about doing that in your form constructor (We force `&nbsp;` to be a space char):

```
public function __construct() {

    foreach ($this->fooChoices as $key => $fooChoice) {

        $this->fooChoices[$key] = html_entity_decode($fooChoice, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
}
```

Comment: And if you need to decode quote marks (e.g., &#039;), you can use `htmlspecialchars_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES)`